Set MQ Channel attributes and MQ client TCP initialization attributes programmatically in Java for IBM MQ client
I have a mqclient.ini file which contains TCP level settings such as ClntRcvBuffSize, ClntSndBuffSize, Connect_Timeout, KeepAlive and SSL settings such as OutboundSNI, AllowTLSV13, etc.
Also I have a CCDT file which contains keepAliveInterval, heartbeatInterval, sharingConversations, and defaultReconnect settings.
How do I set all these programmatically using Java classes for IBM MQ?

You mention Java Classes for IBM MQ - just want to make myself clear - is it JMS Classes for IBM MQ or Base Java Classes where you use classes like MQQueueManager?

You can override the properties via JVM system properties as mentioned here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.4?topic=java-mq-classes-configuration-file - meaning you can se the JVM properties programatically as well. But I think it's better to set the properties through a configuration file or bindings file.

@Shashi I am using com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter. How do I verify if the properties are set correctly? after I set it programmatically using the JVM properties
